# How to increase performance when using MAX function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a view with the below condition:

```
select max(table_name.column1) AS `column1`,
table_name.column AS column2,
max(table_name.column3) AS column3,
max(table_name.column4) AS column4 
from table_name 
where (table_name.column5 = 'message') 
group by table_name.column2
```

The select on this view is causing some performance impact.

The index on the table are :
column1 is primarykey
column2 is indexed
column5 is indexed

Can anyone let me know how to get the better performance from the above view.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). In addition, questions about performance always require an EXPLAIN for the problematic query.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the unseful () around where condtion these can invalid the index usage

```
  select max(table_name.column1) AS `column1`,
  table_name.column AS column2,
  max(table_name.column3) AS column3,
  max(table_name.column4) AS column4 
  from table_name 
  where table_name.column5 = 'message'
  group by table_name.column2
```

and add  composite index on the columns involved string from columns in where and then the column in select

eg:

```
create index my_index on table_name    (column5, column2, column1, column3, column4)
```

Comment: In Explain of the query I find find any change in the rows it's scanning. With () and without () the rows scanned are same.

Comment: Composite index is also not working as expected. Before and after adding composite index also the rows scanned in explain of query are same

Comment: and the time of execution ??  if is not changed  .. then you can't improve the query ..